# How do you SVN KEEP but LOCAL DELETE?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, local, delete-file

I'm done with a project and don't want to keep it locally, but don't want to commit my deletions from my computer or accidentally do it later.  How do you "unrevision" local files so you don't have to worry about deleting them?

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the entire working tree, then there will be no possibility of "accidentally" committing that back to Subversion. The Subversion metadata is stored in `.svn` subdirectories, and if you get rid of those then the link to the server is gone as well.

When you want to start working on that project again, just make a new checkout.